# Remove prohibited HTML tag or fix attributes or value not supported by the AMP standard

Tags: amp-html

We are publishing AMP artilces. For few of the artilces we are getting error in google web master while the content is a valid AMP and also there is no any issue when validated through Structured data testing tool.

URL: http://amp.indiatimes.com/health/healthyliving/10-best-sex-positions-for-men-that-women-love-237820.html

In google webmaster its giving below error:
Remove prohibited HTML tag or fix attributes or value not supported by the AMP standard

The 'tag' media is disallowed
the 'tag' amp-pixel is disallowed
The 'tag' div is disallowed
The 'tag' script is disallowed
The 'tag' span is disallowed

How can I fix this issue? Please help.

Comment: This artilce also having same issue: http://amp.indiatimes.com/news/india/kota-district-collector-writes-open-letter-to-parents-of-iit-aspirants-and-it-really-makes-sense-254464.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try following the guide for [Create Responsive AMP Pages](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive_amp.html).

Here is the list of some components being used in Amp Development.

> - amp-access        Provides AMP paywall and subscription support.
> - amp-accordion        Provides a way for viewers to have a glance at the outline of the content and jump to a section of their choice at will.
> - amp-analytics        Captures analytics data from an AMP document.
> - amp-anim        Manages an animated image, typically a GIF.
> - amp-audio        Replaces the HTML5 audio tag.
> - amp-brid-player        Displays a Brid.tv player.
> - amp-brightcove        Displays a Brightcove Video Cloud or Perform player.
> - amp-carousel        Displays multiple similar pieces of content along a horizontal axis.
> - amp-dailymotion        Displays a Dailymotion video.
> - amp-dynamic-css-classes        Adds several dynamic CSS class names onto the HTML element.
> - amp-facebook        Displays a Facebook post or video.
> - amp-fit-text        Expands or shrinks font size to fit the content within the space given.
> - amp-font        Triggers and monitors the loading of custom fonts.
> - amp-iframe        Displays an iframe.
> - amp-image-lightbox        Allows for an “image lightbox” or similar experience.
> - amp-instagram        Displays an Instagram embed.
> - amp-install-serviceworker        Installs a ServiceWorker.
> - amp-lightbox        Allows for a “lightbox” or similar experience.
> - amp-list        Dynamically downloads data and creates list items using a template.
> - amp-mustache        Allows rendering of Mustache.js templates.
> - amp-pinterest        Displays a Pinterest widget or Pin It button.
> - amp-reach-player        Displays a Beachfront Reach video player.
> - amp-soundcloud        Displays a Soundcloud clip.
> - amp-springboard-player        Displays a Springboard Platform video player
> - amp-twitter        Displays a Twitter tweet.
> - amp-user-notification        Displays a dismissable notification to the user.
> - amp-vimeo        Displays a Vimeo video.
> - amp-vine        Displays a Vine simple embed.
> - amp-youtube        Displays a YouTube video.

**How do I check if my page is valid AMP?**

The AMP validator comes bundled with the AMP JS library, so it is available on every AMP page out of the box. To validate:

1. Open your page in your browser
2. Add `“#development=1”` to the URL, for example, `http://localhost:8000/released.amp.html#development=1`.
3. Open the Chrome DevTools console and check for validation errors.

**How do I fix validation errors?**

> Most validation errors are easy to address and fix. Consider this error:

Here is an image from their document.
[image]

> 1. The first line of the error does its best to estimate where the error happened. Clicking on it should locate the general area.
> 2. The second line, The part in red is the actual name of the error. In this case, MANDATORY_ATTR_MISSING signals that we’ve used a tag and forgot an important attribute.
> 3. The third line points to the piece of the AMP HTML Spec that talks about the limitation or feature in question.

**NOTE**:

> Valid AMP documents must not inlude any validation errors. The purpose of this document is to help you better understand and fix any validation errors you encounter when you validate your AMP pages. For a complete overview of the [validation errors](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate.html), see the [AMP validator specification](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator.protoascii).